# How to detect if query is runned from widget?

Tags: wp-query, widgets, query

I want to know if exists function that detect if some database query run from widget, for example from recent_posts widget or search_widget.

Comment: No, there is not such thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the is_main_query Function :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query

Happy Coding, Kuchenundkakao